# segmentation fault in iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, segmentation-fault, multimap

I have created a multimap for my road points. The key refers to the road number and the values are vec3 points that make up the road.

I am trying to iterate through the values of each key point and create a road segment at each point on the road (except the last), adjust the values to be on the road points and then store them in a std::vector.

The RoadSegment constructor creates 6 vec3 points and pushes them onto a std::vector.

I have a segmentation fault in the line marked in bold
[for(mapIt = it.first; mapIt != it.second; ++mapIt)]

When i take out the lines creating the new objects and pushing them onto the std::vector it works fine.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is / a solution to the problem??

Many thanks in advance

```
std::vector<glm::vec3>::iterator SegIt;

for(int i = 0; i < m_genRoads->getKeyValueData().size(); i++)
{
    int numberDesired = m_genRoads->getMultimapData().count(i) - 1;

    std::multimap<int, glm::vec3>::iterator mapIt;
    std::pair<std::multimap<int, glm::vec3>::iterator, std::multimap<int, glm::vec3>::iterator> it;

    it = m_genRoads->getMultimapData().equal_range(i);


    for(mapIt = it.first; mapIt != it.second; ++mapIt)
    {

        int distance = std::distance(it.first, mapIt);

        if(distance != numberDesired)
        {
            RoadSegement* roadSegmentPointer = new RoadSegement();

            // FUNCTIONS TO ADJUST COORD VALUES TO MATCH THE ROAD POINTS


            m_segmentArray.push_back(roadSegmentPointer);

        }

        else
        {
            continue;
        }

         ///SOME BUFFER BINDING STUFF
```

Comment: probably with ++mapIt you are going out of the space of your map. try changing in mapIt++

Comment: I just tried that but it did not work.... still gives a segmentation fault

Comment: @FrankCunningham: `++mapIt` and `mapIt++` *do* the same thing; the only difference is the value of the expression (before or after the increment), which this code is ignoring.

Comment: Can you narrow down when/where the error occurs?  Which iteration, for example?

Comment: @willgosling Please post `getMultimapData().`  I can smell that you're returning a temporary.

Comment: I put in a std::cout just before the new RoadSegment(). It prints out once and then stops

Comment: std::multimap<int, glm::vec3> GenerateRoads::getMultimapData()
{
    return m_roadsMultimap;
}

Comment: m_roadsMultimap is a std::multimap<int, glm::vec3>

Comment: @willgosling Bingo, that's the problem.  You're returning a temporary map.  That guy is gone and any iterator usage of it is invalid.

Comment: but if i take out the lines RoadSegment *roadSegmentPointer = new RoadSegment(); m_segmentArray.push_back(roadSegentPointer); and  replace it with a std::cout<<"MAKE ROAD SEGMENT"<<std::endl; it works fine and prints multiple times

Comment: @willgosling - Make the change suggested in the answer.  Your code is invoking undefined behavior by using invalid iterators, so removing/adding lines of code doesn't really do anything useful (except showcase how bad code can do weird things).

Comment: The major standard library implementations support checked iterators for debugging, which would have found this problem instantly. e.g. for GCC try compiling your code with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` to use the Debug Mode containers, which would abort as soon as you try to use an invalid iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you're using iterators that do not exist, all due to returning a temporary object.

`it = m_genRoads->getMultimapData().equal_range(i);`

Since `getMultiMapData()` returns a copy of the multimap, that multimap is gone after the line is executed, thus rendering any iterators invalid.

One solution is to return a reference to the multimap, not a new copy of the multimap.

`std::multimap<int, glm::vec3>& GenerateRoads::getMultimapData() { return m_roadsMultimap; }`

Comment: Thats great it works thankyou. Does that mean that any function that calls a return which is used in a loop should return a reference or is it a case by case thing?

Comment: It has nothing to do with loops. You just cannot use an iterator to a container that doesn't exist. Returning from a function by value creates a new temporary object that then disappears again, so any iterators into that temporary object are invalidated immediately.

Comment: The issue is a matter of object lifetime.  In your original code, the multimap returned will last until the next statement.  By returning a reference, you're returning the same multimap your class was using, not a copy.  There is nothing inherently wrong with returning a copy, but you have to make sure the copy lasts as long as you want it to, and in your case it didn't.